# Is it always true that the CRC of a buffer that has the CRC appended to the end is always 0?

Tags: error-handling, crc, crc16, lfsr

Example of the hypothesis...
Is it always true that the CRC of a buffer that has the CRC appended to the end is always 0?

```
extern uint16_t CRC16(uint_8* buffer, uint16_t size);  // From your favorite library

void main() {
   uint16_t crc; 
   uint8_t buffer[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

   crc = CRC16(buffer,8);

   buffer[8]= crc>>8;      // This may be endian-dependent code
   buffer[9]= crc & 0xff;  // Ibid.

   if (CRC16(buffer,10) != 0) 
    printf("Should this ever happen???\n");
   else
    printf("It never happens!\n");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the CRC is modified after it's calculated, such as some CRCs that post complement the CRC after it's generated, then generating a new CRC using data + appended CRC will result in a non-zero but constant value. If the CRC is not post modified, then the result will be zero, regardless if the CRC is initialized to zero or non-zero value before generation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it always true that the CRC of a buffer that has the CRC appended to the end is always 0 ?

Depends on the CRC, and how it is appended. For the 16-bit and 32-bit CRC "CCITT" used in networking (Ethernet, V42..), **no**: the final CRC (appended in the specified order) is a *constant*, but not zero: `47 0F` for the 16-bit CRC, `1C DF 44 21` for the 32-bit CRC. 16-bit example

```
-------- message --------            CRC-CCITT-16
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08                 D4 6D
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  D4 6D          47 0F
DE AD BE EF                             CB E5
DE AD BE EF  CB E5                      47 0F
```

That comes handy in telecom, where often the layer handling receive knows that the frame ends only after receiving the CRC, which was already entered in the hardware checking the CRC.

The underlying reason is that the 16-bit CRC of 8-byte message `m0 m1 … m6 m7` is defined as the remainder of the sequence of `/m0 /m1 m2 m3 … m6 m7 FF FF` by the generating polynomial.
When we compute the CRC of the message followed by the original CRC `r0 r1`, the new CRC is thus the remainder of the sequence `/m0 /m1 m2 m3 … m6 m7 r0 r1 FF FF` by the generating polynomial, and therefore the remainder of the sequence `FF FF FF FF` by the generating polynomial, thus a constant, but has no reason to be zero.

[Try it online in Python!](https://tio.run/##1VTBTuMwEL37K0aqRGLRRk7S7Ua7AgnaVOIEgmoPoCVyEjex1Nhdx@y2/Hyxk1ICokgggbS@jeeN5/k9e5ZrXUoRbjY9qDUVOVU5@KNByjWML8cg5zAen81m8GsY9OEsjmO40nlEAi9EOZtbTNIAEn/kVvgHArMyOAKymprVhHOpIAUuoGrT0GJujyD9@bRhUcKiFBUFcyPcAT8e6mbHxz6@dckqGpLoYOBmBz7GaHdep6li@k4JyDwtk3StWe0GfWfBtV4wByPUg5xVEtmmpW164xCfBCQkQ/KNjMh3Ejl9ZxKfTE7jeOr8brlUdWFI2NOoUnTtzZWsSrZyyy0FZTk@V6Qu2txScaFt6NkCfOiAc2jwnehlnU3jNo9RW254o45NYfABm8LgFZs@1ap4chpFYUD22fWGZcOvtsyq8xHL2rr9ltGKvdu3Hgiq@V9m73rR/FIInRrSO77QA7OXckHrjHPEq6VU@il@aXgyPbma7VzfqvyI9gzn5k3sVb0h//9KLw37zkD7x7W9AtecLvi9EdjIanyBJc1zLoo2f8@UZPVOyOv48rw737YSul0Nk/LPyq36BONnEyflxee/3R2/9@nXKXtVvs3mAQ). Includes 16-bit and 32-bit, "by hand" and using external library including one where the constant is zero.

For CRCs that do not append the right number of bits, or output the CRC wrong-endian (these variants are legion), the result depends on the message. This is a sure sign that something is wrong, and that correspondingly

- the receiver can no longer enter the message's CRC into the CRC checker and compare the outcome to a constant to check the integrity of the message.
- it is lost the the desirable property of CRC that any error concentrated on a sequence of bits no longer than the CRC is caught (if we do not get the CRC straight, an error that overlaps the end of the message and the CRC can sometime remain undetected)